# is there a way to get the inherited width of position:absolute elements?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here the second div is positioned absolute. first div is taking 60% of outer div width, but the second div is taking 60% width of the whole screen. I know that by giving position: relative for the first div will solve the problem.Is there a way to solve it other than by giving position: relative?

```css
.outer {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

.first {
  background: black;
  width: 60%;
  color: white;
}

.second {
  position: absolute;
  width: inherit;
  background: yellow;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="first">
    parent
    <div class="second">
      child
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

If the outer div will have a defined width you can rely on CSS variable to define the percentage and inherit will work like expected:

```css
.outer {
  height: 100px;
  --w:100px;
  width: var(--w);
}

.first {
  background: black;
  width: calc(0.6 * var(--w));
  color: white;
 
}

.second {
  position: absolute;
  width: inherit;
  background: yellow;
  color: black;
 
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
<div class="first">
  parent
  <div class="second">
    child
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Here the width 100px is sample case scenario, so this will not work in my case. Is there any other option to inherit percentage based values specified in outer div and all other child need to inherit those values ?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know in advance the width of your parent, you can compute its width in javascript with a `document.getElementById('parentID').getBoundingRect().width` and use that value to resize your child element to 60% of this value.

But why would you not want to use `position: relative` on the parent ?

Comment: I know that this method will work, and also I prefer using document.getElementById('parentID').offsetWidth rather than using getBoundingClientRect(). But there another way of converting a percentage based value provided to parent element to pixels for easy inheritance by child?